# Create set with custom comparator passed as lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, set, predicate

I was writing the solution for [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/vertical-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree/) and needed to create a `set`, well actually an `unordered_map` from int to my custom `set`, without further ado, this is what I came up whith:

```
auto comparator = [](pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) {return a.second == b.second ? a.first < b.first : a.second < b.second; };
unordered_map<int, set < pair<int, int>,decltype(comparator) >> H;
```

The rest of code is not relevant. Here the compiler complains that

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
<lambda_6dd753bdcbaf959c162af7914f0815bf>(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function"
```

Can anyone please describe that is compiler trying to tell me, or even better if you could hint what I have done wrong.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code shown [doesn't reproduce the problem](https://rextester.com/WOUN92452). So the rest of code is too relevant. Show a [mcve]

Comment: Which compiler ?

Comment: In addition to a [repro], please also provide the full compiler output. The error message comes with additional notes detailing what went wrong. Also mention which C++ standard version you are compiling for. There were changes in C++20 regarding this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that it needs to invoke the default c'tor for that lambda type you defined. However, it is only in C++20 and beyond that a captureless lambda is default-constructible. Prior to that *all* lambdas cannot be default constructed, they only spring into existence from a corresponding lambda expression (or copied of course).

I recommend using a custom functor type for this.

```
struct Comparator {
  bool operator()(pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) 
  { return a.second == b.second ? a.first < b.first : a.second < b.second; };
};

unordered_map<int, set < pair<int, int>, Comparator  >> H;
```